R studio is not saving my tabs when I re-open
What is the correct procedure for making sure R Studio saves my tabs (i.e. scripts) when I close R-Studio and then re-open?  Currently, all my tabs are gone; I want to make sure they are retained.
I've tried:
In Global Options, I've checked restore .RData into workspace at startup. I hit apply and OK, and yet still when I open a new R Studio session nothing is saved.
I've also tried to load workspace from the "session" dropdown and load the .RData workspace, and while it loads all my variables, none of the tabs are retained.
I never had an issue until updating R Studio to the latest version.

It would be better ask for help at the RStudio support site https://forum.posit.co/ or file an issue on github https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues. IDE tabs are not stored in .RData files. Those are for R itself, not the IDE. Make sure to add your OS and the exact RStudio version number you are using in your question

I believe you want to check the "Restore previously open source documents at startup" checkbox, which is accessible from the Tools menu, Global options... General, Basic tab.

